# Can a RadioGroup span more than one layout?

Tags: android

I have sucessfully made and used RadioGroup's before in xml, but each time there was a set of radio buttons in succession, all within the same LinearLayout. Now I wish to define a set of radio buttons to be part of a group, but they are not in the same layout. My start and end code for the group is:

START:

```
<RadioGroup    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" >
```

END:

```
</RadioGroup>
```

If I place this around each button individually, then it compiles, but the buttons don't act as radio buttons (i.e. activating one did not de-activate the others). If I try to place the "start" before any of the buttons and put the "end" after the last of them, then I get compilation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the RadioButtons in an array. Instead of grouping them in a RadioGroup, you have to enable/disable them yourself. (un-tested so no copying/pasting )

declare these variables

```
private ArrayList<RadioButton> mGroup = new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        for(RadioButton btn : mGroup)
            btn.setChecked(false);

        buttonView.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your activity:

```
mGroup.add(your radiobuttons);    // e.g. (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button1);
mGroup.add(another radiobutton);

for(RadioButton btn : mGroup)
   btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener)
```

Maybe you have to invalidate your Buttons after checking/unchecking them, to cause a redraw

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the SDK does not directly support doing this, you would need to create a custom "group" to manager the buttons.

All the mutual exclusion logic for each `RadioButton` is managed by `RadioGroup`, so all the buttons have to be added to the same group.  `RadioGroup` is a subclass of `LinearLayout`, so this inherently means they also need to all be in the same layout.  `RadioGroup` manages each button's checked status by iterating through its children, which is why the two can't be divorced.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/RadioGroup.java) to the `RadioGroup` source code as a starting point, you could create a custom Manager that uses the same logic here to manage the status of which button is checked in order to separate them from their layout status.  `RadioGroup` basically just registers itself as an `OnCheckedChangeListener` for each child that is a `RadioButton` and then controls the check status of all the buttons based on user events.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refined and tested version of the first part of Entreco's code:

```
    final ArrayList<RadioButton> mGroup = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            for(RadioButton btn : mGroup) {
                if (buttonView.getId() != btn.getId() && isChecked) {
                    btn.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

It will uncheck only the other buttons and only if the state of the clicked button changed from unchecked to checked.

Answer (score 1):

@Entreco answer can cause recursive call to `onCheckedChanged` which is fixed by @Twilite answer.

But @Twilite answer also has a problem and that's the `id` of views without explicit id may not be unique. If that happen, you may see either multiple selected radio buttons or none of them being checked. So, it's safer to either set a unique id or a unique tag for each one:

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {

            for (RadioButton btn : mGroup)
                if (!btn.getTag().equals(compoundButton.getTag()))
                    btn.setChecked(false);

        }
    }
```